# What is the best way to make a chart like this? (historical balance of a certain address)

Tags: web3js, dapps

[image]

I wonder how to make a chart like this.

1. It shows the historical balance of specific tokens.
2. It shows total net worth in $.
3. It should be on the Polygon chain.

I've been looking through 3rd party services but I wondered what would be the best way to implement this function on my dApp.

I really want to know how dappRader and Debank provide this kind of chart for hundreds and thousands of people.

Any concept explanation would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you want to maintain your own database of balance ? How many tokens you plan to track for each address ? Do you have access to archive node? It's very difficult to build if you dont use third party service.

Comment: Hi, So 10,000+ users will use our app to track their balances. Tokens that will be tracked will be around 5,000+ tokens. 

I don't have an archive node. Is archive node necessary to do what I want? and what third party services you recommend? I looked through The Graph but seems like it doesn't match with my purpose.